Unable to burn Windows 11 ISO image in macOS 14 (Sonoma)

macOS Sonoma 14.4.1 (23E224)

Downloaded Windows 11 ISO image on mac and now I want to create a bootable USB so that it can be used to install Windows 11 on my desktop PC, but found no free software on macOS, but some command line utility from here (solution 3)
Boot Camp Assistant also not supported on this M1 chip.
It failed on last command.
rsync -avh --progress /Volumes/CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9/* /Volumes/WIN11/.

rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/ce725a5f-c761-11ee-a4ec-b6ef2fd8d87b/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
What could be the issue here?
Also, can someone suggest me authentic guide how to burn Windows 11 ISO image to bootable USB?

What machine are you going to install Windows 11 on?

going to install on desktop.

sadly bootcamp app is not woking in mac os 14 and microsoft community suggest to use some paid software

The link given in your question does not appear to work.

You aren't installing an x64 Win11 ISO on an M1 Mac for the same reason there is no BootCamp for an M1 Mac.  Not supported.  If you think you need Win11 on an M1 Mac, you need to use virtualization, whether Parallels or Fusion or UTM.

I dont need win11 on mac. I just want to nurn the iso file and ned to install it on my desktop using USB

its -- actually

It's not clear if you're intending to install Windows directly on your M1 Mac (only possible with the ARM version & virtualization software like UTM) or just need to create a proper bootable Win11 USB on your Mac for use in another PC.
If it's the latter, I suggest this open-source app: WinDiskWriter.

I have said that I want to install windows 11 on my desktop ( other system ) not on mac os

Thanks it worked. I have to allow it from Settinsg > Privay amd Security and it works great and burn the iso image. . Thanks again

but another issue came. I tried to butn another iso, win10 and it stopped in middle and now my USB is not visible / detected in any of OS :(

@xkeshav Sounds like possibly a faulty USB stick, but I have had luck reviving those by putting them in a PC and using diskpart followed by list disk, select disk X where X is your USB drive, and then clean.

diskpart not listing the USB at all :(
